# Testing a method in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing

I'm writing my first test in rails and I have a method which checks if the name passed through the animal object is valid. (Will return the name if valid or `nil` if not)

animal_verifier.rb

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

    class AnimalVerifier
      def initialize(last_sync_at, force_sync_ids)
        @last_sync_at = last_sync_at
        @force_sync_ids = force_sync_ids
      end

      def valid_animals
        animals.each do |animal|
          if !is_valid_animal(animal.name)
            Rails.logger.info("Invalid animal name")
            next
          end
        end
      end

      def is_valid_animal(animal_name)
        animal = AnimalFinder.find(animal_name)
      end

    end
```

animal_verifier_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class AnimalVerifierTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  test "valid animal" do
    valid_animal = @is_valid_animal.send("Beluga")
    assert valid_animal?, "valid animal"
    puts valid_animal.errors unless valid_animal.errors.empty?
  end

  test "invalid animal" do
    valid_animal = @is_valid_animal.send("Puddle")
    assert valid_animal?, "invalid animal"
    puts valid_animal.errors unless valid_animal.errors.empty?
  end
end
```

When I run this test I get the error:

```
NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `Beluga' for nil:NilClass
```

Does this mean I don't have a class for `AnimalVerifier`? I just want to test the specific method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@is_valid_animal` is never initialized in your test, so it's `nil`, that's why you see the error `undefined method ... for nil:NilClass`. You should create an object under test first and then call methods on that.

When you call `object.send("Beluga")`, a message "Beluga" is sent to the `object` and it tries to invoke a method named `Beluga`. If it fails to find it in default case it raises an error of `undefined method Beluga`

Your test should look more like:

```
  test "valid animal" do
    verifier = AnimalVerifier.new(last_sync_at, force_sync_ids) # you need to init those thow params that are passed to the constructor
    valid_animal = verifier.is_valid_animal("Beluga")
    assert valid_animal, "valid animal"
    puts valid_animal.errors unless valid_animal.errors.empty?
  end
```

Note that I removed the question marks that were appended to method and variable names.

Comment: OH. that makes so much more sense... I'l look into that. Thanks a lot!